# Better Graphics for Windows Direct2D, OpenGL or what?

Tags: windows, graphics, euler-math-toolbox

I have an old, large application which I want to update with better, faster graphics. The application (Euler Math Toolbox) needs a fast graphics, but also a good looking one. I would like to have anti-aliasing at least, and maybe transparency.

Currently I draw to bitmaps off screen, and copy the content to the screen at redraw events. For the anti-aliasing, I generate a larger bitmap, which I reduce for display.

So, what is my best way to modernize this? Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Direct2D is better, if only Windows use planned.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd535473%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: You should probably argument why Direct2D is better, otherwise this answer is kinda pointless...